# What is the Performance difference between Joomla 1.5, 2.5 and 3.0?

Tags: performance, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

We have website developed in Joomla 1.5, 4 years ago.
We are changing the theme of the website now. As we dont need any new components or plugins, I just want to know is there any advantage of upgrading from 1.5 to 2.5 or 3.0.

Is there any performance advantage between 1.5, 2.5 or 3.0?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

firstly, it's not **just** about performance, there are other reasons for upgrading.

**Security** - There are no known security issues in Joomla 1.5.26 however 2.5 and 3.2 (especially 3.2) have far better security.

**Support** - Support for Joomla 1.5 was stopped in September 2012 and I believe Joomla 2.5 will continue to be supported until December 2014 and Joomla 3.x untill December 2016.

**Features** - Joomla 3.2 contains so many more feature such as

- Mobile Responsive
- Ajax Interface integrated into the core
- Ability to install extensions via the backend
- [and much more](http://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5516-joomla-3-2-0-stable-released.html)

**Performance** - To simply answet this question, yes, Joomla 3.x performance is better than Joomla 1.5. I couldn't find a raw demo for Joomla 1.5 but [here is a speed test of a raw Joomla 3.2 site](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/v8L5F/http://joomla32.cloudaccess.net/):

Do also bare in mind that there are lots of extensions out there to boost the performance even more by compressing and gzipping scripts/stylesheet and so on.

And out of all honesty, I do believe that if something works then why change it (in some cases) but you also have to understand that things are moving forward, such as new web technologies are being introduced which will help improve your site.

Overall, I would most definitely upgrade your site to Joomla 3.2

Hope this helps

Comment: Technically speaking, since 1.5 is way too old, it's not updating -   it's **migrating**. There are lot of changes in Joomla since version 1.5. And yes, I agree, I would also upgrade..

Comment: Thorough and convincing answer Lodder

Comment: ACL, tags, versioning, responsiveness, strong passwords, jquery, no more sections, smart search, core layouts without tables, responsive design.

Comment: I am not saying anything related to the question, but how does pingdom show the performance of a cms?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to update your website. Joomla 1.5 is outdated and no more supported.
 
To name briefly few of the reasons: 
Old code, No more security releases, compatibilities issues with newer PHP, many 3rd party extensions are dropping support. You just can't stay that way back.
Just visit joomla.org to find out more and about the benefits and the new features of Joomla.